# TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined (line 54, file "Code")

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, typeerror

I got stuck here. I have read several solutions but still not able to figure out what is wrong. what to do?

```
    function sendPDFForm()
        {
          var row = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getRow();
          sendEmailWithAttachment(row);
        }
    
function sendEmailWithAttachment(row)
{
  var filename= 'Poster-CoV-WS-E1-merged.pdf';
  ...
}
    
    function getClientInfo(row)
    {
       var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('test');
       if (sheet != null) {
          var values = sheet.getRange('A2:B4').getValues();
         //var values = sheet.getRange(row,1,row,3).getValues();
         var rec = values[0];
       }
      var client = 
          {
            first_name: rec[0],
            email: rec[1]
          };
      client.name = client.first_name;
      return client;
    }
    
    function sendFormToAll()
    {
       var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('test');
      
       var last_row = sheet.getDataRange().getLastRow();
      
       for(var row=2; row <= last_row; row++)
       {
         sendEmailWithAttachment(row);
         sheet.getRange(row,4).setValue("email sent");
       }
    }
```

[image]

here I have shared the complete code. While running it it is showing error inline 54 only

Comment: Error is not here. It's probably somewhere else or `sheet` is ``null``(Is the sheet name correct?)=>`rec` is `undefined`

Comment: yes sheet name is correct its test only

Comment: Which line is line54?

Comment: first_name: rec[0],

Comment: Then sheet name is wrong. Test a another name or Show result of ``Logger.log(sheet)``

Answer (score 2):

**Error explanation**

You need to learn to read error messages, otherwise it will be very difficult going forward. The message states:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined (line 54, file “Code”)

Let's parse the meaning of the message:

1. This is a [`TypeError`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypeError#:%7E:text=The%20TypeError%20object%20represents%20an,that%20operator%20or%20function%3B%20or) related to a primitive value [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/undefined)
2. The running script tries to access a property named `0` from `undefined`
3. The instruction that causes the error is located on line 54, file "Code.gs"

Now, "try to access" means that you instructed the script to invoke a [*property accessor*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) on an object. Since the message refers to property `0`, it is likely that you tried to access an *element* in an array by its *index*, which you did: `rec[0]`.

As you got a `TypeError`, you expected `rec` to be an array, but instead the variable holds `undefined`. You initialized the `rec` variable (btw, see point 1 below) to `values[0]`, and `values` to the result of calling `getValues()`.

Because [`getValues`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) *always* returns a two-dimensional array of values, it cannot be the problem. Then, as has been pointed out, the only other choise is that the `if` statement block is never reached, meaning that `sheet != null` is `false`.

The only reason why `sheet != null` is because [`getSheetByName()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename) returns `null` if a sheet cannot be found. Here is a small sample reproducing the error:

```js
function MCVE(testValue) {
  
  if(testValue != null) {
    var test = "not null";
  };
  
  test || console.log("Expected test to be defined");
}

MCVE(null);
```

**Optimization points**

1. Never use variables [out of scope](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp). Your `rec` variable is declared in an `if` statement, but accessed outside of the statement.
2. Keep opening `{` on the same line with the statement or function declaration. JavaScript assumes a lot for you, so one day you may miss the interpreter deciding to put an `;` after your `if` statement...
3. Do not for the love of god use I/O (input / output) operations in loops (see `setValue` in your `for` loop) - they are slow, and in Google Sheets they are *very* slow, use `setValues()` instead (and move `getRange()` out of the loop as well).
4. Use [strict comparison](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) (`===` / `!==`) unless you know what you are doing. 99% of the time using strict comparison teaches you paying attention to correctly using types and avoids frustrating bugs. For example:

```js
const nonStrict = false == "0";
const strict = false === "0";

nonStrict && console.log("non-strict comparison evaluated to true");
strict || console.log("strict comparison evaluated to false");
false || console.log("false is falsy");
"0" && console.log("but non-empty string is truthy");
```